# How can this SQL be wrong? What am I not seeing?

Tags: sql, mysql

**Can anybody please spot my error, this should be a legal query in SQL shouldn't it??**

> Unknown column u.usr_auto_key in the ON clause

This is the database schema:

```
User: (usr_auto_key, name, etc...)
Setting: (set_auto_key, name etc..)
User_Setting: (usr_auto_key, set_auto_key, value)
```

And this is the query...

```
        SELECT 
        `u`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u__usr_auto_key`, 
        `s`.`set_auto_key` AS `s__set_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u2__usr_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`set_auto_key` AS `u2__set_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`value` AS `u2__value` 
        FROM `User` `u`, `Setting` `s` 
        LEFT JOIN `User_Setting` `u2` ON `u`.`usr_auto_key` = `u2`.`usr_auto_key` 
        WHERE (`s`.`sct_auto_key` = 1 AND `u`.`usr_auto_key` = 1 AND admin_property is null)
```

Comment: Did you check that there isn't a typo in the table itself instead of the query? Has happened to me more than once. The query was correct, but I had mistyped the column name when I created the table.

Comment: No it is auto-generated. Pablo Santo Cruz' answer is correct. However I don't understand :). (Btw Pablo contains a typo, it should be User, not Users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching `User` and `Settings` in the from clause:

```
SELECT 
        `u`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u__usr_auto_key`, 
        `s`.`set_auto_key` AS `s__set_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u2__usr_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`set_auto_key` AS `u2__set_auto_key`, 
        `u2`.`value` AS `u2__value` 
        FROM `Setting` `s`, `Users` `u`
        LEFT JOIN `User_Setting` `u2` ON `u`.`usr_auto_key` = `u2`.`usr_auto_key` 
        WHERE (`s`.`sct_auto_key` = 1 AND `u`.`usr_auto_key` = 1 AND admin_property is null)
```

Comment: is it working?

I think if you do: Users u, Settings s left join WHATEVER, you are trying to perform the join on Settings, not Users.

Answer (score 4):

Don't mix SQL-89 "comma-style" join syntax with SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax.  There are subtle issues with the precedence of these two types of join operations.

In your case, the consequence is that it's evaluating the join condition `LEFT JOIN` before the `u` table alias exists.  That's why it doesn't know what `u.usr_auto_key` is.

You can correct this problem by using `JOIN` syntax for all joins:

```
SELECT 
  `u`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u__usr_auto_key`, 
  `s`.`set_auto_key` AS `s__set_auto_key`, 
  `u2`.`usr_auto_key` AS `u2__usr_auto_key`, 
  `u2`.`set_auto_key` AS `u2__set_auto_key`, 
  `u2`.`value` AS `u2__value` 
FROM `User` `u` JOIN `Setting` `s`
LEFT JOIN `User_Setting` `u2` ON `u`.`usr_auto_key` = `u2`.`usr_auto_key` 
WHERE (`s`.`sct_auto_key` = 1 AND `u`.`usr_auto_key` = 1 AND admin_property is null)
```

I didn't see any join condition between `u` and `s` in your query, so I assume you intend this to be a Cartesian product?

---

For more details on the interaction between the two syntax forms for join, see the section **Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12** on the page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

---

Re your comment:  As I said, it has to do with operator precedence.  If you have a SQL query with `FROM A, B JOIN C` then it evaluates the `B JOIN C` before it pays any attention to `A` -- that includes assigning table aliases.  So if your join condition for `B JOIN C` uses the table alias for `A` you get an error because that alias doesn't exist yet.

If you reverse it and run `B, A JOIN C` then as it evaluates the join condition for `A JOIN C` the alias for `A` is available and it works (in this case at least).

But this is a fragile solution, because you might also need a query that can't be fixed just by reordering `A` and `B`.  It's better to just stop using the outdated join syntax with commas.  Then any join expression has access to all your table aliases and you'll never have this problem in any query.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a cartesian product. However I was unable to use cross-join. Can you please explain why the `u` alias IS created in Pablos answer just because it is specified second instead of first (as in my original query)?

Comment: Thanks for elaborating 'all the way'. I just really need this approach because my ORM framework Doctrine doesn't correctly execute a CROSS JOIN query...

Comment: Tip: a cross join is equivalent to an inner join with no condition, or with a condition that is always `true`.

Comment: In other words, there is really, *really* no reason to use comma-style join syntax.