# MySQL 1054 Unknown Column in On Clause (MySql5.7)

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench

Query:

```
SELECT orphans.DIST_NAME, orphans.BRAND, orphans.DIST_ID, orphans.PROD_NAME as ORPHAN_PROD_NAME, dist.pack as Dist_Pack
FROM orphans, dist
INNER JOIN dist di
    ON di.DIST_NAME = orphans.DIST_NAME
INNER JOIN dist ds
    ON ds.DIST_ID = orphans.DIST_ID;
```

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'orphans.DIST_NAME' in 'on clause'

All of my fields are text fields. No matter how I do anything, the query won't run.

Comment: is there a dist_name field in your orphans table?

Comment: I'd expect that column to only exist in the `dist` table, and you use the `JOIN` to translate from the `DIST_ID` to `DIST_NAME`.

Comment: Why are you joining with `dist` 3 times? You also shouldn't mix implicit joins with explicit joins (best to get out of the old habit of implicit joins completely).

Comment: @Barmar, it exists in both tables, as it's common identifier for a product. I'm not quite sure of what you mean by an implicit join... I am joining the other two times to match up the columns in the tables...

Comment: @MarcB, yes it does exist in both tables...

Comment: `implicit join` is using multiple tables in the `from` clause.

Comment: Implicit join is when you list tables separated by comma. Explicit join is when you write `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660544/20860 for a detailed explanation.